# how to check if a folder is opened in python with os module [Close]

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I want to know if someone opened my folder. I tried this but it still not working.

```
import os

while True:
    try:
        open(r"C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Bureau\Myfolder")
        print("The folder has been opened !")

    except IOError:
        continue
```

Comment: What do you mean by "someone opened my folder"?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you run the code and what happens instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want when I open Myfolder a message says "The folder has been opened"

Comment: A folder cannot be "opened", files can be opened.

Comment: ok, ty I will try something else ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.